# How to find the next step to go

Tags: r, reinforcement-learning

Having a dataframe like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(
    n1 = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0),
    n2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
    n3 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0),
    n4 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    n5 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0),
    n6 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    n7 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
)
```

and a graph like this:

```r
library(igraph)
plot(make_full_graph(7), vertex.name = head(LETTERS))
```

in which the column names of the dataframe is the names of nodes of the graph.

Using a shortest path option from reinforment learning algorithms how it is possible to make it?

Comment: Hi, what you want to do is quite unclear (at least for me) .. can you detail a few steps ?

Comment: Also please fix your code, the dataframe is not valid, I think you mean the package `igraph` and what does the dataframe represent, what is the "next demand"?

Comment: (1) The data frame is 'valid' in the sense that it creates a data frame, but it is not easy to see what it means. n1 - n7 are the nodes, but what are the rows? Time steps seems right, but there are rows with no one value and a row with 2 ones. (2) In your full graph example, all nodes are connected directly (that is what full graph means), so the shortest path is _always_ a single hop.

Comment: You could detail a few steps .. imagine that I don't know anything about your toy and your graph, and how does the toy move in this graph, from a node to another ... (I write "imagine" but in fact, this is the reality, even after I read your question)

Comment: I see the edits to your data frame, but I still don't quite get it. It looks like the toy is at node 1 in step 1 (first row in `df`) but then there is no location in the next two rows - where is the toy? - and then _two_ locations in the next one. Is it easier to give a sequence of nodes to visit? For example: nodes <- c('n1','n3','n2'). Note again though: with a full graph, _all nodes are connected_ so your sequence will be identical to the path. Unless of course your graph has edge lengths, but you haven't mentioned those

Comment: @David_O I updated the dataframe. Yes the graph connections are identical

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the answer you are looking for, but you would have more luck asking this at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), as your question deals more with **method** than code.

That being said, I would highly recommend taking a look at [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ReinforcementLearning/vignettes/ReinforcementLearning.html) regarding the `ReinforcementLearning`-package for R.